# How to bind backbone.js events to JQuery UI dialogue windows?

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm very new to backbone.js but we're starting to use more and more JS on the front end and I wanted to use some framework to give the code structure - backbone seems to suit our needs.

So started off with [a very simple test app](http://jsfiddle.net/cocovan/hMyE2/) that launches a dialogue window using jquery-ui. The problem I have is that since jquery-ui adds a wrapper DIV round the original template used by backbone, the events no longer fire.

I don't want to use the jquery-ui event model as I'd rather just use the one - how can I bind backbone's to this new structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - at the end of this project, I finally realised that I hadn't answered this. What happens is when you create a .dialog with JQueryUI, it actually detatches your original DOM element and moves it to the bottom of the DOM wrapped in it's own JQueryUI markup to turn it into a dialog.

Since the Backbone view's element has now been moved, Backbone doesn't pick up any events that fire as it's happening outside it's own "view" as far as it is concerned.

So what you have to do is reassign the view's element:

```
var dlg = this.$("#dialogue-properties").dialog({ ..});
this.setElement(dlg);
```

Where `this` is the view. This is done within the `initialize` method

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the call to `_.template()` is actually doing the wrapping in an extra div.  The parent div with the events bound to it is being left behind appended to `#well`.  A simple workaround is to call .parent() on the result of getting the element with the model class ID.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqeGY/) for example

There's more than likely some information in the _ documentation that might shed some more light on the problem too.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I had tried using parent() to get hold of DIV but not sure I had it in the right place. Will try again.

Comment: not sure as not too familiar with backbone. You could use jQuery parents('.thing-youre-interested-in') then it wont matter if has an intervening DIV - sometimes a different way of referincng the element can solve code issues I find.

Answer (score 0):

You can create div wrapper in your view and modal it's content, as described [here (first part of the post)](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/)

Comment: thanks for that but it's not actually modal windows I'm working with here. The problem isn't elements being removed from the DOM but extra ones being added in around my template that I want to control.

Answer (score 0):

**cocovan** does a good job explaining the problem in his answer. However, as for the solution, the JQuery UI team actually added a method at the end of 2012 ([Allow dialog to be attached to a element other than body](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7948)) that takes care of this issue.

It is the `appendTo(selector)` method ([jQuery Dialog appendTo method](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo)). So simply specify to which element you want the dialog appended.